# External keyboard in flutter support

Tags: flutter

How can I collect chars from external keyboard and append to a var without having a text field?
Im trying to setup a Bluetooth/USB barcode scanner to automatically to something when scanned but not that you have to click a field (or see one)
And have a credit card reader Automatically do everything in the background..

Comment: Hi there..could you manage to connect the usb barcode scanner?? I'm starting to try using one so i'm garhering infos but all i found so far is this post . Thanks

Answer (score 9):

`RawKeyboardListener` allows to do that https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RawKeyboardListener-class.html

```
  var _focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return RawKeyboardListener(
        child: Text('raw keyboard input'),
        focusNode: _focusNode,
        onKey: _onRawKeyEvent,
      );
  }

  void _onRawKeyEvent(RawKeyEvent event) {
    ..
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same position and after some researches, I believe that **RawKeyboardListener** is actually not the best thing to use. Instead, there's a **Widget** called **FocusScope** that appears to be a perfect fit for this purpose. The best thing about this **Widget** is that its **onKey** event won't be triggered by any text field, nor will it be triggered by soft keyboard.

Comment: Hey I know it's a bit old but, can you provide a sample of how to implement that actually. I can't make any sense from the documentation. Also does this Widget prevent another widget from the next route from getting the focus?