# How do I handle physical button event with Dart and Flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, keyevent

I'm sorry for such a generic question, but I don't know where to start:

**How do I handle physical button event in Flutter/Dart?**

(on a device with custom button for example)

Can you point me to a tutorial or some documentation, please.

Thank you in advance for your help

Francesco

Comment: Check if it results in keyboard events https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200938/external-keyboard-in-flutter-support/54201076#54201076

Comment: thanks for your answer Gunter, my tag was deceptive,
I've checked your link, but I'm trying to listen to 
a custom button which should return an int,
it's a sort of custom device.

Comment: It probably is still a keyboard event. Have you tried?

Comment: I'm trying and you might be right Gunter, the problem is that it's an industrial scanner, it might be able to get the data from the scanner attached to the 'key' event... any help would be great

Comment: What have you tried? . .

Comment: yeah, I read the 'key' being pushed and released... at least it's something
found a paleolithic post https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?273258-Listen-to-keyboard-input-(Barcode-Scanner) that might have solve it, wish me good luck


oh... wait, do you think the sensor package can do it?

Comment: I didn't use the sensor package yet, but if it is a keyboard the RawKeyboardListener should do what you need. If not you might need to modify the engine or perhaps building a custom plugin might allow implement that feature which would make it easier.

Comment: sensor is my plan b, can you point me at some tutorial for the keyboard event? thanks in advance

Comment: I only tried it once with https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22905#issuecomment-456019176 I don't have more information.

Comment: I needed to go for another way...
this is the new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54423831/receiving-data-from-a-scanner-kotlin-code-and-send-it-to-flutter-via-methodcha

Comment: You've mentioned that you've come up with a solution on the other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54423831/receiving-data-from-a-scanner-kotlin-code-and-send-it-to-flutter-via-methodcha). It would be helpful for the community if you can share it here.