# Receiving data from a scanner [kotlin code] and send it to Flutter via MethodChannel

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, flutter, intentfilter

[Edit 4th February 2019]
I gave up Kotlin and I'm really out of my comfort zone using java,
I think I-m almost there but I-m getting this error

> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on
>   channel scanner)

here's my last code, 
I could use some help:

java side

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity implements EventChannel.StreamHandler {

  static IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
  static String mAction = "++++CENSOR++++";
  static final String mKey = "++++CENSOR++++";
  static final String mEventCall = "scanner";
  private PluginRegistry.Registrar mRegistrar;
  private EventChannel.EventSink mEventSink;

  public void registerWith(Registrar registrar) {
      MainActivity plugin = new MainActivity();
      final EventChannel channel = new EventChannel(registrar.messenger(),mEventCall);
      channel.setStreamHandler(plugin);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    filter.addAction(mAction);
    registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver, filter);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy()
  {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver);
  }

  private BroadcastReceiver myBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      String action = intent.getAction();
      if (action.equals(mAction)) {
        try {
            String data = intent.getStringExtra(mKey);
            mEventSink.success(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
      }
    }
  };

    public void onListen(Object o, EventChannel.EventSink eventSink) {
      mEventSink=eventSink;
    }

    public void onCancel(Object arguments) {
      mEventSink=null;
    }
}
```

flutter side

scanner.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Scanner {
  static const String mEventCall = 'scanner';
  static const EventChannel _eventChannel = const EventChannel(mEventCall);
  static Stream<String> _readingStream;
  static Stream<String> get readingStream {
    if(_readingStream== null){
      _readingStream =_eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream().map<String>((value)=> value);
    }
    return _readingStream;
  }

}
```

main.dart

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Scanner Beta',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  Stream<String> _stream = Scanner.readingStream;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("test"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          initialData: "",
          stream: _stream,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
            return Text(snapshot.data);
            }
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[edit: 30th Jan]
I've checked the [suggested link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187680/flutter-how-to-call-methods-in-dart-portion-of-the-app-from-the-native-platfor), for sure it gives me a better insight
of a context I'm not yet familiar with, but I believe my problem is of a different nature:
I try to explain myself better:
1. (native app on the device) -> broadcast INTENT and ACTION
2. (my kotlin broadcast receiver) -> receive INTENT and ACTION
3. (MISSING PART) ***need to get the data from the intent/action to MethodChannel***
4. (my kotlin MethodChannel) -> sen data to Flutter via platform invokeMethod

once again thank you in advance for any help you can give me
Francesco

[original post]
I'm trying to build an app to read a scanner data (and other stuff with that)
I (kind of / think I) know how to use a methodChannel 
to pass the data from kotlin to flutter,
the scanner doesn't have a real plugin, but I can use a BroadcastReceiver
+ IntentFilter to listen to the 'scanner action';

my problem is to put both together,
how can I make sure that whenever the Br..Receiver 'receive' something
it will pass it to the method channel 
(WITHOUT touching the screen [this is the device](https://www.gammasolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/zebra-tc8000-touch-mobile-computer.jpg))

Bonus, I'm really out of my comfort zone with this task
I might (probably) made some mistake, I can really use another pair of eyes

Here is my code:
//////////////// KOTLIN

```
// get data from scanner API
import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.content.Intent;

//send data to flutter
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;

class MainActivity:FlutterActivity() {

    private var scanData:String? = null


    private val SCANNER_ACTION = "++++censored++++"
    private val SCANNER_INTENT_DATA = "++++censored++++"
    private val FLUTTER_CHANNEL = "scanner.data"
    private val FLUTTER_METHOD = "getScannerData"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState:Bundle?) {


        private const method_flutter = MethodChannel(flutterView, FLUTTER_CHANNEL)

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        //send intent to flutter
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
       method_flutter.setMethodCallHandler{
            methodCall, result ->
            if (methodCall.method == FLUTTER_METHOD) {
                if (scanData!=null) {
                    result.success(scanData)
                } else {
                    result.error(null,null,null)
                }
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }

        ///scanner INTENT FILTER
        val filter = IntentFilter()
        filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
        filter.addAction(SCANNER_ACTION)
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
    }

     // END OF 'onCreate'
     // SCANNER RECEIVER
     private val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
         override fun onReceive(contxt: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
             if (intent?.action == SCANNER_ACTION) {
                scanData = intent.getStringExtra(SCANNER_INTENT_DATA)
             }
         }
     }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        unregisterReceiver(receiver)
    }
}
```

////////////////DART

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

    class Plugin {
      static const platform =  MethodChannel('scanner.data');
      Future<String> get data async => await platform.invokeMethod('getScannerData');
      }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter: How to call methods in Dart portion of the app, from the native platform using MethodChannel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187680/flutter-how-to-call-methods-in-dart-portion-of-the-app-from-the-native-platfor)

Comment: I'll check it out, butvi don't think bthis is it, tahnks for bring it up

Comment: If you get stuck using that other answer, update this question or post a new one.

Comment: update at the bottom of the initial post, edit: do you think I should use  PlatformMessages instead?

Comment: Why wouldn't you call a method in the Dart portion of the app from the kotlin code, passing the scanner data as a Uint8List? You've added the broadcast receiver to your flutter project, right?

Comment: updated with both flutter and java code, plus error message

Comment: You are really close, and I can't immediately see what's wrong. If you'd like to continue with the `EventChannel` route, I'd grab a copy of the `connectivity` plugin [source](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/connectivity) and get that working unchanged, then gradually change it to remove the WiFi bits and add your scanner data event. (I've never used `EventChannel` in the main project, only in a plugin, so there's something obvious we are missing I guess. I see why you want it in the main project, to be close to the definition of the BroadcastReceiver.)

Comment: The other thing to try is to ditch `EventChannel` and go back to the original link I sent which allows you to call a Dart method from Java. Create a Dart method `onScannerData(Uint8List data)` and hook that up as shown. Then call that from java with your scanner data.

Comment: I've managed, as soon as I have time I'll post the solution,
thanks everyone for the help and the support

Comment: @FrancescoIapicca could you share to us your solution in this issue?