# Detect when user is not interacting the app in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to show some Screensaver type of screen when the user is not interacting the app for 5 minutes. So is anyone know how to achieve this kind of functionality in flutter.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const timeout = const Duration(seconds: 10);
const ms = const Duration(milliseconds: 1);
Timer timer;

void main() =>
    runApp(MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var home = MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page');
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: home,
    );
  }


}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _goToSecondScreen() {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _goToSecondScreen,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    ), behavior:
    HitTestBehavior.translucent, onTapDown: (tapdown) {
      print("down");
      if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
      }
      timer = startTimeout();
    },);
  }

  startTimeout([int milliseconds]) {
    var duration = milliseconds == null ? timeout : ms * milliseconds;
    return new Timer(duration, handleTimeout);
  }

  void handleTimeout() {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenSaver()),
    );
  }

}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container();
  }
}
class ScreenSaver extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GestureDetector(child:Container(color: Colors.yellow,),
      onTap: (){
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is the sample code which I am trying to achieve the functionality. When the screen in active in Second screen its not working and the `GestureDetector` stops listening.

Comment: Just update a time every time  a user is interacting and check frequently if the time wasn't updated since a certain amount of time.

Comment: Where do I listen the touch event? There are multiple screens in the app.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer please check the code, I don't know how to deal the context issue.

Comment: I saw your update, just didn't have time yet to have a closer look.

Comment: No problem, please check when you got time.

Answer (score 7):

You can wrap your whole app in a `GestureDetector` with `behavior: 
 HitTestBehavior.translucent` to receive touch events while allowing widgets in your app also receiving these touch events.

You might also want to listen to keyboard events [External keyboard in flutter support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200938/external-keyboard-in-flutter-support/54201076#54201076)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will try listening on `onTapDown`

Comment: I have wrapped the app in `GestureDetector` but the issue is when I launch an screen from the event it worked only when it is on Parent Widget. If it is on another screen the I can not launch another screen due to context. So how can I handle the `context` issues.

Comment: Please create a **minimal** reproduction as a single file including imports and `main(){...}` and add it to your question so that I (and others) can investigate.

Comment: I have added the sample code in the question please check

Comment: Exactly my thoughts! I came to SO to see if there are other methods, happy to see your solution is similar to mine.