# Detect when user interact with the app (Flutter)

Tags: button, flutter, user-interaction, gesturedetector

I need a little help there.

I want to disconnect the user from the app when he has been inactive for 5 minutes. So I used this solution : [Detect when user is not interacting the app in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54999917/detect-when-user-is-not-interacting-the-app-in-flutter)

It is perfectly working when the user tap on a widget that is not clickable. For example, when I tap on Text widget, the timer is restarting without an issue, but when I tap on a RaisedButton or ListTile, the timer is not restarting.

So, I'm wondering how it is possible for example with this code :

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => print("gestureDetector"),
  child: RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () => print("raisedButton"),
  ),
),
```

to print "gestureDetector" AND "raisedButton".

Thank you in advance for your help, cheers ;)

Comment: Btw, I've tried to use IgnorePointer widget or the behavior property of GestureDetector : not working :'(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a `Listener` instead of `GestureDetector`.

```dart
Listener(
  onPointerDown: (e) => print('listener'),
  child: RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () => print('raisedButton'),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for this quick answer and the solution is working fine ! Love u mate :D

Comment: You sir need a medal. This works very nicely to handle session management.