# How to check if App is not being used while in Foreground in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter app, I wanted to check if a user is not using the app while they are in Foreground. `WidgetsBindingObserver` only checks if the app is in the foreground/background. and if the app has resumed, inactive, detached, or paused. but how can I check if the user is not using the app in the foreground at a specific time?

```
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);

    if (state == AppLifecycleState.detached ||
        state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) return;

    final isBackground = state == AppLifecycleState.paused;

    final isForeground = state == AppLifecycleState.resumed;

    if (isBackground || isForeground) {
      Get.offAll(Login());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to run a periodic timer that gets reset whenever the user taps the screen.

So set up something global to do just that. Set it to X seconds and reset to 0 when the user tap is detected. If the timer reaches Y seconds you know that it is not used by the user.

[Flutter - Detect Tap on the Screen that is filled with other Widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60163123/flutter-detect-tap-on-the-screen-that-is-filled-with-other-widgets)

https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-flutter-timer-class-timer-periodic/

Hopes this helps you in the right direction

Comment: Indeed here are some other useful stackoverflow posts:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59067562/detect-when-user-interact-with-the-app-flutter
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54999917/detect-when-user-is-not-interacting-the-app-in-flutter

Comment: do i need state management and create a global Timer?