# TextField overflow when pressing `Tab` key in Simulator from System keyboard -Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Textfield behaviour changes when pressing `Tab` key from the System keyboard. The `maxlines` property is set to 1 in `TextField`. My app got rejected by the Apple Team due to this issues. So please help.

[image: Here is the screenshot of the issue]

Comment: "Textfield behaviour changes" can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Please check screenshot

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am having multiple textFields and when I start typing to textField and press tab key from keyboard, TextField do behave like that... user inputs are getting overlap in textfields. It should hide the keyboard or move to next TextField

Comment: Related issues https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10372, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11344. You might need to add a RawKeyboardListener and handle that yourself until this is fixed (for example like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200938/external-keyboard-in-flutter-support/54201076#54201076)

Comment: Ok..
But RawKeyboardListener not working.. I already tried this way

Comment: Then I don't know. It's a while I used RawKeyboardListener myself.